# Solving for $x$ given $y = 2x - 9$ and $y = 5$. When does the 5 come into play?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am doing some problems. It states "Isolate the left side for each of the following equations. Then solve for x, assuming the value of y is 5 in a all cases." I noticed that I can get two different answers, depending on when I decide to plug in the value of y. For example, this is what I get:

$$ y = 2x - 9 $$
$$ 9 + y = 2x -9 +9 $$
$$ 9 + y = 2x \frac{1}{2} $$
$$ \frac{1}{2} * 9 + y = x $$
$$ x = \frac{1}{2} * 9 + 5 $$
$$ x = \frac{9}{2} + 5 $$
$$ x = \frac{19}{2} $$

But, if 5 is plugged into y in the beginning, I've seen it done like this:

$$ 5 = 2x - 9 $$
$$ 5 + 9 = (2x - 9) + 9 $$
$$ 14 = 2x -9 + 9 $$
$$ 14 * \frac{1}{2} = 2x * \frac{1}{2} $$
$$ x = 7 $$

Which one is correct?

Comment: Try putting your answers back into the original equation. If you want to diagnose where the mistake is, calculate each side line by line - then you will see where you are going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The first one has an error in it. When you multiply $9+y$ by $\frac{1}{2}$, the $\frac{1}{2}$ multiplies both the $9$ and the $y$, not just the $9$.  The second one is correct, except you have an = in place of a + between the 5 and the 9.  It doesn't matter which method you use though, to answer your question.

Comment: Okay, makes sense, multiply both by 1/2.

Comment: Right. The second solution seems to be more in the spirit of the directions they give as well, and it's easier.

Answer (score 1):

The first is wrong because you forgot to multiply $y$ by $\tfrac12$. When you got into

$$
9 + y = 2x
$$

By the law of equations, you should do as follows:

$$
(9 + y) = 2x \\
\frac12(9+y) = \frac12 2x \\
\frac12(9+y) = x
$$

The you plug the value of $y$

$$
\frac12(9 + 5) = x \\
\frac12 14 = x \\
x = 7
$$

Answer (score 1):

You have a mistake in the first. The second has no mistake.

For the first, note that
$$\begin{align}9+y=2x&\iff \frac{1}{2}\left(9+y\right)=\frac 12\times 2x\\&\iff \frac{9+5}{2}=x\\&\iff x=7.\end{align}$$
Note that you need to multiply $9+y$ by $\frac 12$.

Comment: Thank you! Slowly but surely I'm learning bits at a time.

Comment: @CosmoCosmo: You are welcome. Enjoy learning math!